# Java Implementing a Client Server Model (Using TCP) and sending a IP address from server and Printing it out on Client

Tags: java, server, tcp, client, byte

Server code:

```
package exp1;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MyServerSocket{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(2050); 
          System.out.println("server is waiting..."); 
          Socket s=ss.accept(); 
          
          InetAddress ad= InetAddress.getByName("hostname");
          OutputStream os=s.getOutputStream(); 
          System.out.println("s"+ ad.getHostAddress());
          byte ins=Byte.parseByte(ad.getHostAddress());
          os.write(ins); 
          
          ss.close();
    }
    

}
```

Client code:

```
package exp1;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class MyClientSocket {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Socket s=new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),2050); 
    InputStream is=s.getInputStream(); 
    System.out.println("Client is ready to receive data"); 
    int d=0; 
    while(d!='#') 
    { 
    d=is.read(); 
    System.out.print((char)d); 
    }        
    }
}
```

Error:

Server side:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
> string: "ip"
>
> at
> java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString([NumberFormatException.java:67](https://NumberFormatException.java:67))
>
> at
> java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt([Integer.java:660](https://Integer.java:660))
>
> at
> java.base/java.lang.Byte.parseByte([Byte.java:193](https://Byte.java:193))
>
> at
> java.base/java.lang.Byte.parseByte([Byte.java:219](https://Byte.java:219))
>
> at
> exp1/exp1.MyServerSocket.main([MyServerSocket.java:14](https://MyServerSocket.java:1

I'm trying to display the localhost's ip on client but I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getHostAddress` returns a string representation of an address. So, this method returns something like `192.168.1.100` which can't be parsed to a byte. You can pass your string as an array of bytes, but this is not optimal solution, since IPv4 address is just 4 bytes, but string `192.168.1.100` is 13 bytes long!

Also, I don't understand purpose of line `while (d != '#')` since you never send any `#` symbols.

Here is the code that works for me

```java
class MyServerSocket {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2050);
    System.out.println("server is waiting...");
    Socket s = ss.accept();

    InetAddress ad= InetAddress.getByName("hostname");
    try (OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream()) {
      System.out.println("s"+ ad.getHostAddress());
      os.write(ad.getAddress());
    }
    ss.close();
  }
}

class MyClientSocket {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Socket s=new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),2050);
    try (InputStream is = s.getInputStream()) {
      System.out.println("Client is ready to receive data");
      byte[] address = is.readAllBytes();
      InetAddress ad = InetAddress.getByAddress(address);
      System.out.println(ad.getHostAddress());
    }
  }
}
```

P.S. closing all resources you open is a good practice to avoid leaks. In the example, I've used [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construction.

Comment: Is there a way to not use InetAddress on client side? We do those part on server and send it to client and the client only prints it out. Thanks for the help by the way :)

Comment: You can do `os.write(ad.getHostAddress().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))` on the server side and `String ad = new String(address, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` on the client side

Comment: Thanks! Works sweet :)